# Assuming that probability is 0.25, How to exactly apply Bayes' theorem on that? in opposed to "the likelihood is 0.25"?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Wiki gives this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Example) to illustrate likelihood.

> Imagine flipping a fair coin twice, and observing the following data: two heads in two tosses ("HH"). Assuming that each successive coin flip is i.i.d., then the probability of observing HH is

${\displaystyle P({\text{HH}}\mid p_{\text{H}}=0.5)=0.5^{2}=0.25.}$

> given the observed data HH, the likelihood that the model parameter $p_\text{H}$ equals 0.5 is 0.25. Mathematically, this is written as

${\displaystyle {\mathcal {L}}(p_{\text{H}}=0.5\mid {\text{HH}})=0.25.}$

> This is not the same as saying that the probability that $p_\text{H} = 0.5$, given the observation HH, is 0.25. (For that, we could apply Bayes' theorem ...)

Assuming that probability is 0.25, How to exactly apply Bayes' theorem on that? in opposed to "the likelihood is 0.25"?

Comment: That does seem a bit obscure.  If, say, our prior is just that $p_H$ is chosen uniformly at random from the interval $[0,1]$, then the probability that we observe $HH$ is $\int_0^1x^2dx = \frac 13$, but the probability that $p_H=\frac 12$ is $0$...we are dealing with a continuous distribution and the probability of getting any specific value is $0$.   If the author is intending a different prior, that needs to be specified.

Comment: Bayes' theorem could be used to, say, compute the probability that $p_H$ falls in the interval $[.49,.51]$, for example.  Those are non-zero values.